# Arranging numbers, but outputting variable names

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have got a few variables, and would like to arrange the variables in descending order in an array or arraylist. The problem is once it's arranged, I would like to print out the  variable names, so I want an array/arraylist that would output: three3,eight8,four4,five5,six6,seven7 instead of 32,29,25,19,11,11. How would I get around this problem?

```
double three3 = 32;
double four4 = 25;
double five5 = 19;
double six6 = 11;
double seven7 = 11;
double eight8 = 29;
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot, until you use reflection. And may I know why you are doing this ?

Comment: I will give you key words : ***collection Pair key value java*** , if you want to improve your self , search and don't read answers

Comment: Charaf: then he would still only be printing variables, not the variables names.

Comment: read what i wrote before , i said key , value,variable name will be the key

Answer (score 1):

You should get around this problem by using a `Map`.
`LinkedHashMap` retains the order of its keys so you can iterate over them. You can use a `TreeMap` with a `Comparator` if you want automatic ordering.

```
Map<String, Double> variables = new LinkedHashMap<>();
variables.put("three3", 32d);
variables.put("four4", 25d);
// ...

// variable names:
for(String key : variables.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + "=" + variables.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashMap` like so:

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> mMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();


mMap.put(32,new ArrayList<String>());
mMap.get(32).add("three3");
mMap.get(32).add("four4");
mMap.get(32).add("five5");

mMap.put(25,new ArrayList<String>());
mMap.get(25).add("six6");
mMap.get(25).add("seven7");
mMap.get(25).add("eight8");

mMap.put(29,new ArrayList<String>());
mMap.get(29).add("eight8");


List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>(mMap.keySet());

Collections.sort(list);

for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

    System.out.println(mMap.get(iterator.next()).toString());

}
```

Edit:
Now it works when variables have same number.

Comment: Tried the method your provided, the problem is if 2 variables are equal to the same number, such as three3 = 10 and four4 = 10, it would only print one of the variables. Is there a way for it to print out all the variables, even if 2 variables have the same value?

Comment: @user3706672 Now it prints out all the variabales.